# Exception when consuming a java web-service from a .net client

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I'm consuming a java web-service from a vb .net client. This service returns an object (called serviceResponse) having three fields: an integer and two arrays of bytes

`Dim serviceResponse As MyWebService.serviceResponse = mVaultWebService.downloadData(inputBuffer)`

when the amount of data returned is small everything works fine, but when the amount of data is large I get the following exception (on the client side)

`Timeouts are not supported on this stream.`

and this is the stack trace

```
StackTrace  "  Server stack trace:      at  System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()    
    at     System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.CreateResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebResponse response)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.WebResponseHttpInput.WebResponseInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.BufferMessageStream(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize)    
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception& requestException)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at LeanCost.VaultWebService.LeanCostWS.downloadLeanCost(downloadLeanCostRequest request)     at LeanCost.VaultWebService.LeanCostWSClient.VaultWebService_LeanCostWS_downloadLeanCost(downloadLeanCostRequest request)     at LeanCost.VaultWebService.LeanCostWSClient.downloadLeanCost(Byte[] xml_input)     at LeanCost.LcVaultWebService.CheckOut(Byte[] inputBuffer, Byte[]& xmlDocumentBuffer, Byte[]& zippedFilesBuffer, LcLog& log)"  String
```

This is how the web service is configurated

```
Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding()
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
binding.MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
Dim address As New EndpointAddress(urlAddress)

mWebService = New MyWebService.WSClient(binding, address)
mWebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username
mWebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password
```

I can't figure out what is causing this issue, it seems a setting of the binding or some configuration property not properly set.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the exception says "Timeouts are not supported on this stream" and you're explicitly setting "SendTimeout" and "ReceiveTimeout"... try to remove them.

Comment: Does the error occur after 10 minutes?

Comment: Thanks, at first I did not have the SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout, I added those lines trying to solve the issue but the problem remains.

Comment: The error occures after a variable time and not always...